# Docker и права доступа

Tags: linux, docker

Использую Docker.
Волюмы прокинул без проблем, однако когда внутри контейнера создается файл (например файл логов), то к нему нет доступа от лица моего пользователя.

Так, как файл создаются от пользователя root внутри контейнера. Как это можно порешать ?

Answer (score 2):

Это не совсем правильный путь, но вы можете указать пользователя для контейнера.

В **Dockerfile** инструкция **USER** позволяет указать пользователя или при старте контейнера ключ `-u` или `--user`.

Разумеется такой пользователь должен быть создан внутри образа и если **id** внутри образа будет совпадать с **id** на хосте, то файлы будут доступны.

Но для логов лучше настроить **logging drivers**

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно указать umask пользователя в контейнере 0000, тогда новые файлы будут создаваться с правами: папки 777, файлы 666. А значит сторонние пользователи смогут их редактировать.

Пропишите в Dockerfile команду`RUN umask 0000` и выполните ребилд контейнера.

Или `umask 0000` из bash консоли контейнера